# Simple Graph which is finite and has no K2 as minor.

Tags: graph-theory

I have to think about the graphs which are simple and finite.

> (a) doesn't have K2 as minor
>
> (b) doesn't have K3 as minor
>
> (c) doesn't have K3 as minor and its a connected graph
>
> (d) doesn't have K1,3 as minor

I just started to study graph theory and have no idea from where to think about.. please help me!

Comment: First... do you know what the notation means?  Do you know what the graph $K_2$ looks like?  Do you know what it means for a graph to have another as a minor?  How about what it means for a graph to have another as a subgraph?

Comment: Yes I know the definetion

Comment: Can you share the definitions so we can see that you do?  If you knew the definitions, I'd have thought this a straightforward problem.

Comment: first of all K2 is a graph with two vertices and one edge between the two vertices. To discontain K2 as minor, the graph G should be the graph with no edges ? is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Hints:*

If a graph doesn't have $K_2$ as a minor... then in particular it doesn't have $K_2$ as a subgraph.  Now... remember that a $K_2$ looks like the following:  $\circ - \circ$... it is a graph with two vertices and an edge connecting them.

> If a graph doesn't have $K_2$ as a minor then it doesn't have any edges($\dagger$).  We call such a graph ______

---

Now, remember what a $K_3$ looks like.  If a graph doesn't have $K_3$ as a minor... then not only does it not have $K_3$ as a subgraph, but it doesn't have $K_3$ as a topological minor either.  This will imply that...

> The graph doesn't have any cycles($\dagger$).  We call a graph with no cycles a _______

I intentionally glossed over details.  Make sure that you can prove those statements that I marked with a ($\dagger$).  It might be easiest to do so via contrapositive, that is, to suppose that you *do* have the described feature and prove that that implies you *would* have the described minor.

The remaining two parts to the problem are similar.

Comment: @J.YY Almost.  (b) Is not necessarily a tree.  It could be a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest).

Comment: oh then (c) would be a tree. (d) would be a graph, its degree is <= 2 is ? not sure about (d)

Comment: @J.YY You are correct that (d) implies that the graph's maximum degree is at most $2$.  Now... what sort of shapes can arise from a graph whose degree is at most $2$?  Just disjoint cycles and paths, right?  Try proving this.